# Redirect all requests to the same directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect everything in a specific folder to a file inside the same folder for maintenance.

Any type of access in the folder `card` will have the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /card/?.?
RewriteRule . /card/maintenance.html [R,L]
```

But I'm getting a weird redirect error, like an endless loop of redirects. I have to redirect deeper in the folder, I can't access the folders outside `card`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude `maintenance.html` otherwise that gets redirected as well. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintenance.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/card/
RewriteRule ^ /card/maintenance.html [R,L]
```

Comment: could you explain why you used "^" instead of "." on the rewrite rule?

Comment: another doubt, the use of consecutive rewritecond works like an "AND" statement?

Comment: @MateusSilva the `^` is just habit. It essentially means "anything or nothing", while the `.` means "at least 1 character of any kind". So depends on where you've placed the rules. And multiple rewrite conditions are "AND"ed together, unless you use the `OR` rewrite condition flag.